# What is an inherited method for the function dbSendQuery?

Tags: r, rmysql

I am trying to use RMySQL to run a simple query

```
dbSendQuery(con, "SELECT    * FROM myDB.student;")
```

However, the code above gives me the following error message

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbSendQuery’
```

for signature ‘"src_mysql", "character"’

I am pretty sure that the connection is working, since I get

```
> show(con)
src:  mysql 5.6.27-log [username@servername.com:/myDB]
tbls: student
```

The `con` object is generated using `dplyr::src_mysql`. I was trying to stick to RMySQL using `dbConnect` but it doesn't seem to work properly (`show(con)` is empty).

What am I doing wrong? Sorry I could not provide a replicable example, hope this is enough information.

Comment: That the sort of message you get from an S4-method where you send it the wrong stuff. The first argument to that function needs to be a MySQLConnection and such objects are usually created by `dbConnect`. You are also misspelling `RMySQL`. You should indicate where `src_mysql` comes from and why you think it should be an acceptable substitute for what the documentation says should be something else.

Comment: Everything started when I realized I could connect with `src_mysql` but not with `dbConnect`. Then I noticed that functions from RMySQL such as `show` apparently worked anyways, thus I thought 'it must be kind of the same thing'. This is what made me think it could be an acceptable substitute.